# How to load images larger than MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS with PIL?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to load some images into my Jupiter Notebook but PIL.Image.open() says that the image is too large. The MAX_IMAGE_PIXEL is set in the PIL Image source code but my image is much larger. I'm wondering if there's a way around this?

The code below works for smaller images. I've looked into trying to manually set the MAX_IMAGE_PIXEL but can't seem to do so.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image

im = np.array(Image.open('data/big_image.jpg'), dtype=np.uint8)

# Create figure and axes
fig,ax = plt.subplots(1,figsize=(10,10))

# Display the image
ax.imshow(im)

plt.show()
```

The code above returns the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DecompressionBombError                    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-09854c1c6343> in <module>
      3 from PIL import Image
      4 
----> 5 im = np.array(Image.open('data/big_image.jpg'), dtype=np.uint8)
      6 
      7 # Create figure and axes

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py in open(fp, mode)
   2640         return None
   2641 
-> 2642     im = _open_core(fp, filename, prefix)
   2643 
   2644     if im is None:

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py in _open_core(fp, filename, prefix)
   2631                     fp.seek(0)
   2632                     im = factory(fp, filename)
-> 2633                     _decompression_bomb_check(im.size)
   2634                     return im
   2635             except (SyntaxError, IndexError, TypeError, struct.error):

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py in _decompression_bomb_check(size)
   2566             "Image size (%d pixels) exceeds limit of %d pixels, "
   2567             "could be decompression bomb DOS attack." %
-> 2568             (pixels, 2 * MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS))
   2569 
   2570     if pixels > MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS:

DecompressionBombError: Image size (1435500544 pixels) exceeds limit of 178956970 pixels, could be decompression bomb DOS attack.
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: If that's an RGB image, you'll need about 500 MB of RAM to fit in memory. There are neat solutions to open a subsection or one vertical strip at a time, but none that I know of Pillow supports. If you're sure you need to open the image, maybe look into OpenCV? When I get home I can maybe write an example answer.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewF . I'm trying to open load the image to tile it for an object detection task. I made some scripts that will tile an image and return the bounding boxes with the appropriate tiles, so I think if I can open a subsection of the image I can work with that.

Comment: You can use `libvips` to tile it easily using minimal memory.

Comment: Search like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vips

Comment: @MarkSetchell great, thank you!

Answer (score 19):

The `DecompressionBombError` from Pillow is a [safety feature](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.1.x/releasenotes/5.0.0.html#decompression-bombs-now-raise-exceptions) for web services, but if you trust the source of the image then it's just an arbitrary limit. An RGB image with 1435500544 pixels has 24 bits per pixel, so it would require roughly 4.3 GB of RAM, which is far beyond the [default Pillow limit](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/fdbd719da4c77c7e23e2e9e9b71d0d177f2d3369/docs/releasenotes/5.0.0.rst) of 178956970 pixels ([about 0.5GB for an RGB image](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.1.x/handbook/concepts.html).)
According to their docs, you can do something like:

```py
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
Image.MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS = None

im = np.array(Image.open('data/big_image.jpg'), dtype=np.uint8)
```

And it *should* work. If you anticipate working with large images, a good alternative to Pillow is [OpenCV](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_setup/py_intro/py_intro.html#intro). It's very fast and offers a suite of algorithms oriented around computer vision. The [getting started](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_image_display/py_image_display.html) tutorial covers image loading.

```py
import cv2

# Load an color image as a numpy array
img = cv2.imread('messi5.jpg',1)
```

It's important to note that OpenCV stacks channels as Blue-Green-Red and Pillow stacks them as Red-Green-Blue, but as long as you use the [OpenCV API](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/index.html) you'll have plenty of options to convert to RGB or any other color space you want.

Comment: This was helpful. A small tweak helped the code run: I replaced 
```from PIL import Image, MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS \ MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS = None ``` to 
```from PIL import Image \ Image.MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS = None``` .

I'll also look into OpenCV. Thanks so much!

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect your tweak in case anyone else comes by the thread.